# Authorization Required when downloading from objects.githubusercontent.com

Tags: github, idm

I started downloading [Beekeeper Studio](https://github.com/beekeeper-studio/beekeeper-studio) and [Prisma Studio](https://github.com/prisma/studio). Both have their `.exe` files hosted on GitHub. Everything was fine, but near 90%, both of them stopped downloading; I tried stopping/starting and a popup appeared asking for Authotization!
[image]

I'm using IDM:

[image]

I'm asking this here because I don't know what is the problem. Github? My Internet Connection? IDM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the tool you're using to download the archives is broken.

When you download a release asset from GitHub, the link redirects from the one you provided, using an HTTP 302, to objects.githubusercontent.com, using a special, time-limited, signed URL.  By the time the download failed, the link was no longer valid.  When your program retried the connection, it should have retried using the original URL because an HTTP 302 is a *temporary* redirect, and therefore the user-agent (your browser or download tool) is supposed to access the *original* URL since the redirect might change (which, in this case, it did).

You are probably better off downloading these programs with a tool like `curl` or similar, which will do the right thing and will also have the ability to resume downloads if the remote server supports the `Range` header.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for! Thanks for your great explanation. BTW, I just downloaded both of them again and luckily they reached 100% :-]

Answer (score 2):

[1. right click on the desired file in IDM and select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oKdr.png) `Refresh download address`.

2. The browser page will open for you. Click again on the same link you clicked before.

and Done! Your file should continue downloading.

I hope it is useful for you

Answer (score 1):

1- close all dialogs and open IDM main window.
2- right click on your unfinished task and choose "Refresh Download Address". *It will automatically open the source page (sometimes you should open it yourself if IDM couldn't) and also a small dialog for new link is waiting until you click the download link/button on the target site*
3- resume your unfinished download task.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me but after reading the nice explanation above, it gave me an easier way to get the download back on track instead of redownloading the whole setup again from scratch.
Since I was using IDM, all I did was to pause or stop the download, refreshed the download address, and then resumed the download again.
it continued and finished perfectly without restarting

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For the IDM just copy new download link and paste it. The download will resume.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

-Redownload the file
-Copy the new address link
-paste it into the incomplete downloaded file address
-Resume your download
-Done

Answer (score 0):

I am using IDM and what refresh download adress does is that sometimes when it is clicked it opens the website but and tempts the user to close the little small dialog before it could even refresh it.
Possibly your problem is also caused by this little "trap".

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32744847)

Comment: Hi Abdellah. As you can see I did my very best to turn your post into an answer. If this is however not what you intended please delete it.

Answer (score 0):

to resume the download you just need to replace the old broken download link with the new one in IDM.

and after doing this your downloading will start from where you left it.

IDM have all downloading problems solution.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me hope it does for you.

- Close all IDM windows.
- Open IDM again (don't resume download)
- Right-click on the broken download file and select refresh download address.
- IDM will open the site and prompt(waiting for the new address to resume the file.
- Click on the download link again, and IDM will pick up the new address link for the file.
- Now, try to resume the download.

I hope this helps.